# jQuery check if remote page has loaded in while loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

We're working on an embeded "visualization" in a page. The embeded object is loaded from another URL on the same server (no CORS issues), however once the user has loaded the main page, the secondary resource takes a while to come up (1-5 seconds).

```
<object id="main" width="100%" height="100%">
    <embed src="some-url" />
</object>
```

We'd like to run some sort of spinner during that time, testing if we get a `200 OK` from the embeded resource, before appending it to the page, as there's no good way for us to allow refreshing of the embeded object until it becomes available. This is what I've tried so far:

```
function test_ie_availability(){
    var loaded_page = false;
    var count = 0;
    while (!loaded_page){
        console.log("Test: " + count);
        count = count + 1;
        if(count > 10){
            break;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: access_url,
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if(textStatus === "success"){
                loaded_page = true;
            }else{
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
        if(!loaded_page){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("Sleeping for a second");
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

with `async:true` and `async:false` both producing the same result:

```
Test: 0 z.js:34
Test: 1 z.js:34
Test: 2 z.js:34
Test: 3 z.js:34
Test: 4 z.js:34
Test: 5 z.js:34
Test: 6 z.js:34
Test: 7 z.js:34
Test: 8 z.js:34
Test: 9 z.js:34
Test: 10 z.js:34
undefined
(10) Sleeping for a second
```

I've tried variations upon this with setting the `loaded_page` variable in a `success`/`error` callback, neither of which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a function inside an interval to keep checking to see if it loaded...

```
var interval = setInterval( function () {

    if (document.all["main"].readyState == 4) {

        clearInterval(interval);

        alert("Initialization is ready.");
    }

}, 100);
```

Comment: That sounds very promising. I'll test that implementation, thanks. Didn't know about `set/clearInteveral`

Comment: Tested and got a working implementation, this solved it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(...)` doesn't cause your program to "sleep" – it causes it to *do* something after a given interval.

So your `while` loop runs 11 times without pause, each time creating a new 1s timer that outputs "Sleeping for a second" to your console.

You can remove the loop altogether, and simply add the code to hide the spinner in place of this line:

```
loaded_page = true;
```

Comment: okay, so I should have placed my ajax query in a setTimeout rather than doing them separately.

Comment: You don't need to use `setTimeout`.  The `ajax` `done` function will run when the page has been loaded.

Comment: The problem is before the page has loaded we might get all sorts of errors, including proxy errors, timeouts, and 404s.

Comment: You can test for those errors within the `ajax` call, but looks like @BA_Webimax gave you a good solution.